# Antiderivative of $e^{x^n}$

Tags: integration, analysis, gamma-function

How do you prove the following identity ?
$$\int \exp(x^n)dx = - \frac{\Gamma(1/n, -x^n)}{n \cdot i^{2/n}} + C$$

where $\Gamma$ is the [Incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) and $i$ the imaginary unit (initially, $i^{2/n}$ was written $(-1)^{1/n}$).

Comment: What are you thinking, about the question?  Did you try on your own to solve it (in which case, if yes, please include your efforts in the post, along with specifying at which stop you get stuck).  If not, please understand that this site consists entirely of volunteers, and it is rude to expect us to do your work for you.

Comment: Note $i^{2/n}=(-1)^{1/n}$

Comment: @amWhy Sorry, I have no clue to how I could prove this, initially, I was searching the antiderivative of $sin(x^n)$ on the site integral-calculator.com and the site threw me this identity like it was obvious, but it is not for me...

Comment: Did you even try looking up what the incomplete gamma function is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define
$$
\Gamma(a,z) = \int_z^\infty e^{-t} t^{a-1}\;dt,\qquad a > 0.
$$
So
$$
\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{n},-x^n\right) = \int_{-x^n}^\infty e^{-t} t^{1/n-1}\;dt
$$
Differentiate, using the fundamental theorem of calculus and the chain rule:
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{n},-x^n\right)
&= - e^{-(-x^n)}\;(-x^n)^{1/n-1}\;(-n x^{n-1})
= e^{x^n} (-1)^{1/n-1} (x^n)^{1/n-1} (-n) x^{n-1}
\\ &= n e^{x^n} (-1)^{1/n} x^{1-n} x^{n-1}
= n e^{x^n} i^{2/n}
\end{align}

Therefore,
$$
\int e^{x^2}\;dx = \frac{1}{n i^{2/n}} \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{n},-x^n\right)
+C$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}\left(-\frac{\Gamma(1/n,-x^n)}{n\cdot (-1)^{1/n}}+C\right)&=-\frac{1}{n(-1)^{1/n}}\frac{d}{dx}\int_{-x^n}^\infty t^{1/n-1}e^{-t}dt\\
&= -\frac{1}{n(-1)^{1/n}}\left((-x^n)^{1/n-1}\cdot e^{x^n}\right)\frac{d}{dx}(x^n)\\
&= -\frac{1}{n(-1)^{1/n}} \left((-1)^{1/n-1}\cdot x^{1-n}\cdot e^{x^n}\right)(nx^{n-1})\\
&= \frac{1}{n(-1)^{1/n}} \left((-1)^{1/n}\cdot x^{-(n-1)}\cdot e^{x^n}\right)(nx^{n-1})\\
&=\exp(x^n)
\end{align*}